# Bind a property to a variable (one way binding I guess)

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I call a store. On its `load` listener I need to test a record, and then send a boolean to a variable to set readOnly to my fields.

I don't know how to change that variable which is in my viewmodel's data.I put by default

```
readOnly : {
            value : true
        }
```

in my VM. I catch it in my component with the bind property like this :

```
bind: {
        readOnly: '{readOnly.value}'
   }
```

and then... I don't know.. I thought about writing in a variable *readOnly* the boolean and then catch it on my ViewModel like this :

/*** Variable File ***/

```
Ext.define('routing.utils.Vars', {
    alternateClassName: 'gv',
    readOnly : false
});
```

/*** Store File ***/

```
[...]

listeners: {
        load : function(store,record){
            if(a = b) {
              gv.readOnly = true;
            }
           else {
              gv.readOnly = false;
           }
        }
    }

 [...]
```

/*** ViewModel File ***/

```
formulas: {
   readOnly: {
      get: function(get){
           return gv.readOnly;
      }
   }
}
```

Buy my readOnly doesn't change... How to bind a variable then?

Comment: Can you get your view model from store load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the properties on viewmodel data property with the set method on the viewmodel.

```
yourViewModel.set('readOnly',{
  value:newValue
});
```

You can get your ViewModel from the viewController with this method:

```
viewController.getViewModel();
```

[Have a look here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html) to see how to work with property binding

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just don't know how to call my function in my viewcontroller from my store. In my load listener I guess

Comment: Nvm, I found how to do it. Thanks a lot